# MultiDexApplication does not implement HasActivityInjector

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I use New Android Injector with Dagger 2 by https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe

Before MultiDex support App has worked.
I have added multidex support to app/build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml.
After MultiDex support i have got error logcat by instaling on device

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eusecom.samfantozzi/com.eusecom.samfantozzi.Detail2Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector
>                                                          at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:48)
>                                                          at com.eusecom.samfantozzi.Detail2Activity.onCreate(Detail2Activity.java:19)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

My App.java

```
public class SamfantozziApp extends MultiDexApplication implements HasActivityInjector {

@Inject
DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;

public RxBus _rxBus;

@NonNull
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
        // This process is dedicated to LeakCanary for heap analysis.
        // You should not init your app in this process.
        return;
    }
    LeakCanary.install(this);

    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this);

}

@Override
public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
    return activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;
}




@NonNull
public ISchedulerProvider getSchedulerProvider() {
    return SchedulerProvider.getInstance();
}

@NonNull
public DatabaseReference getDatabaseFirebaseReference() {
    return mDatabaseReference;
}


public RxBus getRxBusSingleton() {
    if (_rxBus == null) {
        _rxBus = new RxBus();
    }
    return _rxBus;
}

private final DemoComponent dgaeacomponent = createDgAeaComponent();

protected DemoComponent createDgAeaComponent() {
    return DaggerDemoComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
            .build();
}

public DemoComponent dgaeacomponent() {
    return dgaeacomponent;
    }

}
```

New Android Injector with Dagger 2 does not support MultiDex ?

Comment: Have ou declared your current Application as the android:name in application tag in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes, i did. But android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication instead of MyApp. Thanks. Put your answer please. I will accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have ou declared your current Application as the android:name in application tag in AndroidManifest.xml?

In your case, you must use the one that extends multiDexApplication.

Comment: I replaced `application` name to `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication` as said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304196/unable-to-get-provider-android-arch-lifecycle-lifecycleruntimetrojanprovider-ja and got this error.

Comment: `android:name` is very important for some reason. Who knows why :)