# Crash Lifecycle Components installing on Kitkat

Tags: java, android

> Process: android.ul.com.ulinappchatdemo, PID: 2840
>                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>   android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/android.ul.com.demo-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/android.ul.com.demo-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4793)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/android.ul.com.demo-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/android.ul.com.demo-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                     at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)

Comment: What's this? It looks like a Garbage to me. Sorry but when you are asking a question, you should put little more details to make it easy to understand what issues you are facing exactly. Hope you will get my point!

Comment: Im using lifecycle components in my app , Im able to install and run the app on my device with marshmallow but when i installed it on kitkat i got this exception.

Comment: As this is the first search result that pops up when searching this problem. Here's the solution: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68296658

Comment: Here is the solution on Stack Overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49058316/2011622

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to Build -> Clean?

Your error is a `ClassNotFoundException` so with the lack o context you provided, assuming that your project works on other API levels, try to clean up and build to see if clears your cache.

Comment: tried but it didnt help

Comment: Well, you must provide way more details then just pasting the stacktrace if you want us to help you out.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using Architecture components (v 1.0.0), support libraries (v 26.1.0) and kotlin language. App just crash with the same exception as above when I try to run it on 19 API device.

Comment: Got the same problem here when run it on android 4.3

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Will glad to know the workaround. :)

Comment: I fixed the issue by making  multiDexEnabled false in build.gradle

Comment: Here is the proper answer for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48304196/1556745