# RuntimeException:ClassNotFoundException android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-lifecycle

I am getting this error only on Android SDK < 5.0. So 4.0, 4.2, 4.3 ect. Anything running Android 5.0+ works flawlessly. Any ideas? Crashes on launch.

Following this guide for setup -> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html

App.java

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(new AppLifecycleListener(this));
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
}
```

AppLifecycleListener.java

```
public class AppLifecycleListener implements LifecycleObserver {
private App app;

public AppLifecycleListener(App app)
{
    this.app = app;
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
public void onMoveToForeground() {
    if (app.getCurrentActivity() instanceof BaseActivity)
    {
        BaseActivity baseActivity = (BaseActivity) app.getCurrentActivity();
        baseActivity.runIsAPIVersionCheck();
        baseActivity.fetchObjectsWithHUD(false);
    }
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
public void onMoveToBackground() {}
```

}

Gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 26

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 71
    versionName "4.9.9"
    multiDexEnabled true
    resConfigs "en"

    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath false
        }
    }

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0'
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0'
```

> 02-28 20:54:03.151 2558-2558/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4563)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer
>                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
>                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4548)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: did you tried `multiDexEnabled false` ?

Comment: @ThomasMary Changing to false produces this error -> Error:Execution failed for task ':App:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: `implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
    // alternatively, just ViewModel
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"
    // alternatively, just LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.0"

    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"` make sure you added all of them

Comment: Just added them all and same error after syncing gradle. (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html)  // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
    // alternatively, just ViewModel
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"
    // alternatively, just LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.0"

    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This ended up being a multdex issue. I followed the docs here -> https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle and it works great now!

Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

App.java:

```
public class App extends Application implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: This very super amazingly cool! Also there's multidex version 1.0.3 also

Comment: do you know why this only occurs for Lower APIs?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones Not 100% sure, just assume there was a bug prior to 5.0 that was fixed.

Comment: fixed? I'm still experiencing the same issue when running my app in lower android versions.

Answer (score 7):

All I had to do was add the following to my `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keep class android.arch.lifecycle.** {*;}
```

Comment: that helped! any idea why? I have `minifyEnabled = false` everywhere and I was runnig debug mode. I migrated my App to use `androidx` and had this issue afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, Somehow android architecture lifecycle files getting omitted with Android bundle on Pie(Android9). So what I did was added keep statement for the same in `proguard-rules.pro`

For AndroidX :

```
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.** {*;}
```

For Support :

```
-keep class android.arch.lifecycle.** {*;}
```

Comment: This did not happen on my test device (Pixel 3) running Android Pie, however I have observed the crash in the wild on Android Pie devices.

Comment: @straya Same will happen when you install from Google Playstore. :P

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your your ProGuard file. This shouldn't be necessary since Android Architecture Components 1.0.0 ([source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes)), but apparently it still is.

```
-keep class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.GeneratedAdapter {<init>(...);}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but the more general solution from Paul LeBeau did the trick