# androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer" on path: /data/app/app-2.apk

Tags: androidx, android-workmanager

I recently migrated my old app's background services to [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager). On recent devices (down to **sdk 22 included**) it looks OK, running repeating work units and scheduling them even across device reboots as expected.

The problem is when I test against old version (old is very relative here), Android sdk 14 which is my `minSdkVersion`. BTW also `WorkManager` should have the same: *Backwards compatible up to API 14* according to [doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/). As stated in title, **error I get is**:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer" on path: /data/app/com.example.myapp.apk
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4822)
```

I don't have any custom WorkManager configuration/initialization, I simply added

```
     implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0'
```

to my module's gradle and used it quite typcally to schedule background operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was caused by `multiDexEnabled true` which I had in defaultConfig for unknown reasons. I found it out after some digging and an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143436663)

Comment: I am also facing the same error, but after adding these dependencies implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:18.0.0',  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'. Turning of the multidex didn't help me. Any other solutions ?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem in **Androd 19**

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49058316/2460094) and [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle) I solved using

Gradle:

```html
multiDexEnabled true
```

Java:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: for kotlin implementation

  override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base)
    MultiDex.install(this);
  }