# Unable to get provider androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializr

Tags: android, viewmodel, androidx, android-mvvm

Getting error while running app which have dependencies `'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03'` and `'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0-alpha03'` on device with Android 4.4.

Works fine in device with Android 6

App getting crashed with error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/**********.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/***********, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5052)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4623)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4563)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/**********.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/********, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: In my case i ran a  android studio performance test between windows and linux when i came back to windows after android studio performance tests in Linux i got this error so i simply Cleaned the project and Rebuild it and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Thanks [Andrews Alves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3688319/andrews-alves)

[From post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304196/unable-to-get-provider-android-arch-lifecycle-lifecycleruntimetrojanprovider-ja)

It was a Dex problem. in android 4.4

1 - in app gradle, inside defaultConfig enable multidex

```
defaultConfig{
  ....
  multiDexEnabled true
}
```

2 - to support multidex in other versions, add this dependency to your app gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

3 - if you have a class that extends Application, make it extend

> MultiDexApplication

if you don't, add this to your manifest file inside application tag

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Besides, if you created a new application, dont forget to add the following to your app/build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

that's it. worked for me

Comment: As a result of these changes, the application opening slowed down. I wonder why.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, Somehow android architecture lifecycle files getting omitted with Android bundle on Pie(Android9). So what I did was added keep statement for the same in proguard-rules.pro

For AndroidX :

```
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.** {*;}
```

For Support :

```
-keep class android.arch.lifecycle.** {*;}
```

Answer (score 4):

For kotlin add this to your gradle  :

```
kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = "8"
        sourceCompatibility = "8"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the official docs about Multidex [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex). Use this link to check the latest multidex gradle dependency version.

if you're using AndroidX

```
dependencies {
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1" // Check this from the link
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version'
}
```

otherwise use

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me nothing of the above worked. Also restarting and invalidating didnt do anything.
After uninstalling the app and "Build > Clean Project" every thing worked as expected.