# Unable to get provider androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

When I add Retrofit to my project (implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.1'), I get error: *"Unable to get provider androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer" on path: ..."*

```
2020-02-08 15:53:43.964 26961-26961/com.example.someapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.someapp, PID: 26961
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.someapp-PDGCAE5vFess56qfT0OPuw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.someapp-PDGCAE5vFess56qfT0OPuw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6699)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6600)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.someapp-PDGCAE5vFess56qfT0OPuw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.someapp-PDGCAE5vFess56qfT0OPuw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7200)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6699) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6600) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.example.someapp-PDGCAE5vFess56qfT0OPuw==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.someapp-PDGCAE5vFess56qfT0OPuw==/base.apk': Bad method handle type 7
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:75)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:38)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:719)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:752)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1005)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2489)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6497)
                ... 8 more
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.someapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.1'
}
```

Comment: This question cannot be answered without a complete list of Gradle dependencies, and running `gradlew dependencies`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Gradle added

Answer (score 1):

I followed some of the recommendations from this post for my project using Retrofit:

[Unable to get provider androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55177386/unable-to-get-provider-androidx-lifecycle-processlifecycleownerinitializr)

I placed this in my build.gradle

```
    multiDexEnabled true 
    compileOptions { 
          sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 
          targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 
    }
```

I did get my app to compile.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm.